# Help with creating a formula for "diversity coefficient"

Tags: entropy, diversity

I am creating a small webapp and a part of it is generating a number (I like to call it diversity coefficient) that would represent how "diverse" someone's listening habits are. The problem is I am not sure how to create a valid formula for what I want. I will try my best to explain what information I have, and what I need as a result, and hopefully someone will be able to provide me with a solution. I guess it's nothing hard or complicated, but I am not that deep into math, so I am not sure how to get what I want (tried playing with different formula ideas for a few day, but could not get what I wanted)…

What I do is gather information from someone's [lastfm](http://www.last.fm/) profile, which is a website that lets you track the music you listen to, and also lets you use all the data that they have stored on their servers to create something with that data (you can see a sample of a profile and what it is about [here](http://www.last.fm/user/pootzko) if you like, just to better understand what it's all about). So let's say you listen to a certain band, and you listen to a number of their songs.

The data that I have is the following:

- total count of how many times you listened to a certain band
- number of different songs (from that band) that you listened to
- total count of how many times you listened to each of that different songs

For example:

- someone listened to a band called FooBar for 1012 times
- he listened to 17 different songs from that band
- he listened to the first of that 17 songs for 100 times, the second one of that 17 for 110 times, the third one 120 times, the fourth one 170 times, the fifth one 500 times and the remaining 12 songs only once per song.

What I would like to have as a result is a number that ranges from 0-100. That number would represent if a person listens to all the songs evenly or if he just listens to one or two song from a band all the time, and all the other song only once or twice and then forgets about them…

A perfect 100 score would be for a person that listened to FooBar for 500 times, 5 different song, each one 100 times… That is as even as it gets.

A score of 0 (or some very low score) would be for a person that listened to FooBar for 500 times, 5 different songs - one of them for 496 times, and the remaining four songs only once per song.

I think that it is some kind of "density" that I want, but how to get to that number… I am not sure. That is where I need your help. I would be happy to provide any additional info to help you help me.

The thing looks like this (if you take a look at these bars each one representing a different song (and its share of total count), that is why I say "density"):

[image: bars sample]

In this example it is clear that Dredg is more evenly spread than Deftones, and should have a higher score (in my case the score is almost the same which is not good, it's just something that remained from my experimenting with the formula).

PS Feel free to edit tags, I really have no clue what to put there.

Comment: I would try to model music by a number of "dimensions" (I don't know enough about music or music theory to know for certain the sensibleness of this endeavor), then plot songs as points in $n$-dimensional space, and then do something akin to computing the [variance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance).

Comment: It sounds like you want to put the [entropy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_%28information_theory%29) on a 0 to 100 scale.

Comment: I tried editing to add tags, but don't yet have the rights.  I recommend adding: entropy, dispersion, statistic.  However, dispersion is not yet a valid tag on CV, which takes even more points to create.

Comment: Look into what ecologists use to measure biodiversity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most fundamentally related topic is [entropy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_%28information_theory%29#Definition).  Scaling it could be done relative to the minimum and maximum entropy of the set, or of the given user.  Personally, I'd recommend scaled relative to a quantile of people who have listened to roughly the same # of tracks.

Another popular measure of dispersion or inequality is the [Gini coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gini_coefficient#Calculation).

Comment: just what I needed! in the end I decided just to calculate the entropy, multiply it by 10 and leave it without scaling it. it's good enogh like that. thank you very much :)